# How do I state a code backwards and replace a letter with a certain character in python 3?

Tags: python

(I apologize for being unclear the first time also, WONDERFUL COMMUNITY! I'm suppose to use elif or if statements.)
Below is what I have so far.

```
userInput = input("Write whatever you want: ")
newWord = " "

def strReplaced():
    for letter in userInput[::-1]:
        if letter == "a":
            newWord = "@"
        elif letter == "e":
            newWord = "#"
        elif letter == "i":
            newWord = "%$"
        elif letter == "0":
            newWord = "*"
        else:
            pass
    return strReplaced

print(newWord)
print(userInput)
```

Must fit accordingly to these instructions, also please explain the code

- Get user input for inputWord
- Code to account for upper and lower case being entered
- Assign newWord to an empty string
- Iterate through letters in inputWord backwards.  Add each letter to newWord as you iterate
- Replace these letters: "a" with "@",  "e" with "#", "i" with "%", and "o" with "*", (hint: use if, elif, else)
- Print newWord

It must have a if and elif statement too like the code I submitted, there doesn't have to be a function. I don't think there should be a range.

Comment: [How do I ask and answer homework questions?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/334822/843953) Is something wrong with your attempt? Does it throw an error? Do you get the wrong output? Please ask a _specific_ question about a problem you're having with your code. Please read [ask]
and the [question checklist](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/260648/843953). Welcome to Stack Overflow!

Comment: Yes  I thought it was clear that it didn't work but going over it again your right i could have been more specific also it was homework i was more so looking for someone to explain what i did wrong not just give straight answer

Answer (score 2):

Everywhere where you use `newword = something`, you can use `+=` instead of `=` to directly append to the string. The rest of your code appears to be right according to your points (is this homework by the way?). You did forget to actually execute your function though: you have it defined but you do not use it by executing `strReplaced()`.

You could also remove the `else: pass` entirely, and `newWord` should probably be initialized to `""` (empty string) instead of `" "` (string with a space). If you want to have a so-called pure function, define your function to have an argument with `def strReplaced(argument_name_goes_here)`.

---

Edit: forgot something, you are currently replacing letters (assuming you use implement the above points) but you are not adding the letters which did not have to be replaced. So don't delete the `else`, but replace `pass` with a statement that appends the letter to the new word (I think you can figure this out on your own).

Comment: thank you for your help idk if you see this cause i dont think that @ works and i dont know how to reply and yes its homework that i dont understand thank you especially for explaining.@asdf101

Comment: if someone comments on an answer or question of yours or @tags you in a comment you get notified, maybe take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) if you haven't yet so you can learn how to use StackOverflow.

Comment: God bless you have a goood weekend.

Answer (score 2):

Do not mess around with loops. Python 3 has a built-in translate function.

```
userInput = input("Write whatever you want: ")[::-1].lower()
userInput.translate(str.maketrans({'a': '@', 'e': '#', 'i': '%$', 'o': '*'}))

Write whatever you want:  This is A sentence to REPLACE
'#c@lp#r *t #cn#tn#s @ s%$ s%$ht'
```

Comment: If the point of their exercise is to learn how to use loops and functions, this does not solve their problem

Comment: troublesome for ```newWord = "%$"```

Comment: @asdf101 so this answer is does not provide any useful information to this user or any other users in the future.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this solution get easier

````py
def test(a):
    dict_word={
        'a':'@'
        ,'e':'#'
        ,'i':'%'
        ,'o':'*'
    }
    b=a[::-1]
    print(b)
    new_word = ''
    c = []
    for i in b:
        if i in dict_word:
            res = dict_word[i]
        else:
            res=i
        c.append(res)
    new_word=''.join(c)
    return new_word


a='sdocisae'
b=test(a)
print(b)
```
````

Comment: While this is an answer to the general problem, the user is being hinted to use an `elif` suggesting the problem is looking for a solution build around `if` statement clauses rather than a dictionary lookup.

Answer (score 0):

You can swap out the if / elif for a dictionary.

```
translate = {
    "a": "@",
    "e": "#",
    "i": "%$",
    "0": "*"
}

def strreplaced(word, translate):
    newword = ''
    for letter in word:
        if letter in translate:
            newword += translate[letter]
        else:
            newword += letter
    return newword

userinput = input("Write whatever you want: ")
print(strreplaced(userinput, translate))
```

Comment: While an answer to the problem, the exercise calls for the use of `elif` and is looking for a beginner's solution.

Comment: Correct I don't think I even need a def if its not neccesary.

Comment: yes, I should have read more carefully :)

Answer (score -1):

There are a number of good answers involving dictionaries and you will likely explore them in the future. You are on the right track though with your initial attempt.

Note the instruction say to account for upper and lower case being entered, but I am not sure what that means. I converted the input to lowercase but that might not be what you want.

If you want either an `a` or an `A` to be converted to `@` and to preserve case in other instances, then you might convert each letter to lowercase prior to testing

```
if letter.lower() = "a":
```

or alternatively test for

```
if letter in ("a", "A"):
```

Here is something that might get you unstuck...

```
## ----------------------------
## let's pass in a parameter to this function
## ----------------------------
def strReplaced(text):
    # we will build up the result one character at a time
    # starting from an empty string
    # Note: this is not really a good method to build a string, but it will work for now.
    strReplaced = ""
    for letter in text[::-1]:
        if letter == "a":
            strReplaced += "@"
        elif letter == "e":
            strReplaced += "#"
        elif letter == "i":
            strReplaced += "%$"
        elif letter == "o":
            strReplaced += "*"
        else:
            strReplaced += letter

    return strReplaced
## ----------------------------

userInput = input("Write whatever you want: ").lower()

## ----------------------------
## Again this is not really the right way to build a string
## you will learn better ways
## ----------------------------
print("input: " + userInput)
print("output: " + strReplaced(userInput))
## ----------------------------
```

If I was going to write `strReplaced()` I would probably start with:

```
def strReplaced(text):
    lookup = {"a": "@", "e": "#", "i": "%", "o": "*"}
    return "".join([lookup.get(letter.lower(), letter) for letter in text[::-1]])
```

But I think you will come to that in a few more lessons

Comment: Since they might not have had string formatting yet ([and string interpolation is discouraged over f-strings and .format](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#old-string-formatting)), maybe replace `print("input: %s" % userInput)` with `print("input: ", userInput)` and similar for the other print

Comment: Yes the one you said to replace '''print("input: ", userInput)''' we do all the time

Comment: Also @JonSG beautiful help this is basically the task we were given and thank you the little lesson. also this answer worked I got useful info from other AWESOME people but none of them seemed to work no matter how much more input I gave, output was always the same. Again thank you and God bless

Comment: Also @JonSG when you gave the example to do                                                                          if letter.lower() = "a": you dont have to do that because when you put .lower in userInput it doesn't matter. I could have interpeted what you were saying wrong.

Comment: I was suggesting that you could do `letter.lower()` rather than `input().lower()` if you liked :-)